# In GMail, is there a way to tell when an email in your account was opened?

Tags: gmail

I suspect someone has been reading my emails and then setting their statuses back to 'unread'.

Is there a way I can check when an email was initially opened?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do that exactly, but one thing you can do is check whether previous people have logged onto your account.

[image]

Click `Details` to see a detailed description of your logins.